# Haskell: Lifting a reads function to a parsec parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

As part of the 4th exercise [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing#Return_Values)
I would like to use a `reads` type function such as `readHex` with a parsec `Parser`.

To do this I have written a function:

```
liftReadsToParse :: Parser String -> (String -> [(a, String)]) -> Parser a
liftReadsToParse p f = p >>= \s -> if null (f s) then fail "No parse" else (return . fst . head ) (f s)
```

Which can be used, for example in GHCI, like this:

```
*Main Numeric> parse (liftReadsToParse (many1 hexDigit) readHex) "" "a1"
Right 161
```

Can anyone suggest any improvement to this approach with regard to:

Will the term `(f s)` be memoised, or evaluated twice in the case of a `null (f s)` returning `False`?

Handling multiple successful parses, i.e. when `length (f s)` is greater than one, I do not know how parsec deals with this.

Handling the remainder of the parse, i.e. `(snd . head) (f s)`.

Comment: This seems relevant: [**`readS_to_P`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:readS_to_P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice idea. A more natural approach that would make
your `ReadS` parser fit in better with Parsec would be to
leave off the `Parser String` at the beginning of the type:

```
liftReadS :: ReadS a -> String -> Parser a
liftReadS reader = maybe (unexpected "no parse") (return . fst) .
                   listToMaybe . filter (null . snd) . reader
```

This "combinator" style is very idiomatic Haskell - once you
get used to it, it makes function definitions much easier
to read and understand.

You would then use `liftReadS` like this in the simple case:

```
> parse (many1 hexDigit >>= liftReadS readHex) "" "a1"
```

(Note that `listToMaybe` is in the `Data.Maybe` module.)

In more complex cases, `liftReadS` is easy to use inside any
Parsec `do` block.

Regarding some of your other questions:

1. The function `reader` is applied only once now, so there is nothing to "memoize".
2. It is common and accepted practice to ignore all except the first parse in a `ReadS` parser in most cases, so you're fine.

Comment: Very nice, I don't know why I didn't think to pass the `String` in, and also thanks for reminding me about the `maybe` function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, no `(f s)` will not be memoised, you would have to do that manually:

```
liftReadsToParse p f = p >>= \s -> let fs = f s in if null fs then fail "No parse"
                                                              else (return . fst . head ) fs
```

But I'd use pattern matching instead:

```
liftReadsToParse p f = p >>= \s -> case f s of
                                        []              -> fail "No parse"
                                        (answer, _) : _ -> return answer
```